# Splitting contents of a dataframe column using Spark 1.4.1 for nested gz file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am having a difficulty splitting contents of a dataframe column using Spark 1.4.1 for nested gz file. I used the map function to map the attributes of the gz file.

The data is in the following Format :

```
 "id": "tag:1234,89898",
 "actor":
 {
    "objectType": "person",
    "id": "id:1234",
    "link": "http:\wwww.1234.com/"
},
"body",
```

I am using the following code to split the columns and read the data file.

```
val dataframe= sc.textFile(("filename.dat.gz")
                 .toString())
                 .map(_.split(","))
                 .map(r => {(r(0), r(1),r(2))})
                 .toDF()

dataframe.printSchema()
```

But the result is something like:

```
 root
 --- _1: string (nullable = true)
 --- _2: string (nullable = true)
 --- _3: string (nullable = true)
```

This is the incorrect format. I want the schema to be in the format :

```
----- id
----- actor
      ---objectType
      ---id
      ---link
-----body
```

Am in doing something wrong ? I need to use this code to do some per-processing on my data set and apply some transformations.

Answer (score 0):

This data looks like JSON. Fortunately, Spark supports the easy ingestion of JSON data using `Spark SQL`. From the [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets):

> Spark SQL can automatically infer the schema of a JSON dataset and load it as a DataFrame. This conversion can be done using SQLContext.read.json() on either an RDD of String, or a JSON file.

Here is a modified version of the example from the docs

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val myData = sc.textFile("myPath").map(s -> makeValidJSON(s))
val myNewData = sqlContext.read.json(myData)

// The inferred schema can be visualized using the printSchema() method.
myNewData.printSchema()
```

For the makeValidJSON function you just need to concentrate on some string parsing/manipulation strategies to get it right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi brian, its a gz file. I have to upload gz files and spark does not have a support for it and the data looks like JSON but is not.

Comment: @user2122466 Hmmm, Perhaps a hack would be to read it in, and map it to a flat (one object per record) `RDD[String]`, then use the `DataFrameReader` `json` function by passing it your new RDD. Here's the link to the DataFrameReader docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html

Comment: Hi brian , thank you for the information. Can you please give me a code example of that ? I have never used it before.

Comment: Well, now that I think of it, you mention your data isn't quite JSON format, so my solution will not work until you create valid JSON. Here is an example of how valid JSON would be for your data: `{"id": "123","actor": {"objectType": "person","id": "id:1234","link": "http://wwww.1234.com/"},"body": "sdfsdf"}`. I edited the above answer to be a little more in context.

Comment: Hey Brian @brian , I tried writing the function :makeValidJSON as you mentioned in the code earlier. But it throws an error "error: not found: value makeValidJSON" and "error: overloaded method value json with alternatives , (jsonRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
[INFO]   (jsonRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
[INFO]  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
[INFO]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing])
[INFO]  val myNewData = sqlContext.read.json(df1)". Can you help me with that ?